# Users in different domain not seeing list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, share, trusted-domain

We are using SharePoint Online with Office 365. We recently acquired another company who had their own domain....we'll call us "domainus" and them "domainthem". We now have a 2-way trust between both domains.

In "domainthem"'s SharePoint site, there is a subsite for Accounting that contains a PO list.  I (as an owner, logged in with an account @domainthem), shared the Accounting site with some users in domainUS.  Those users can now access the Accounting site just fine, but when they go to the PO list, it does not show them any of the items, even when in the "All Items" view.

I did go into the List settings and into "Permissions for this list" - it does show these users as being members of a group that has Contribute permissions for the list.  And I know there are items in the list because I can see them myself when logged in with @domainthem.

Is there something about users in a different domain, even if shared, not being shown list items?? (I tried searching for info on this but couldn't find anything).  What can I do to make it so they can see / modify the items as expected?  Thank you!

Comment: Is there item level permissions enabled for list items?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Amal Hashim's comment, I learned that the list has Item-level permissions set to only view / edit items submitted by 'you' (List Settings -> Advanced Settings).

So to enable my shared users to see all items, I had to give them the Design permission level on that list.